# Possible translations for "it's been cloudy for a week"

Tags: grammaire

I'd like to know which of these are legitimate translations of "it's been cloudy for a week":

> il y a des nuages depuis une semaine
> le ciel est nuageux depuis une semaine
> c'est nuageux depuis une semaine
> le temps est nuageux depuis une semaine

Are there any other common ways of saying this that I've missed, and what would tend to be the most common way of expressing this intended meaning?

Thanks!

Comment: "It's been" + a period of time = "**Cela fait** une semaine que le ciel est nuageux, par exemple.

Comment: @Lambie That's what the OP will see in the linked question, you don't agree it's a duplicate?

Comment: @Lambie Come on! It doesn't make any difference, the question is not about negative or not negative.

Comment: The problem is that that answer provides every possibility when in fact I think **the most common way of saying this from the English "it's been" some period of time is **only**: Cela fait** and not all the others. So, it really is not a duplicate, in that sense. And that is the entire specific answer to this question and what the OP didn't know.

Comment: @Lambie  They can all be used for expressing "it's been + perfect" some might be preferred according to context but OP isn't giving  context.  Moreover the linked answer says "So the perfectly popular spoken sentence would be "Ça fait deux ans ...".  ( *Cela* is mentioned as written style which is perfectly correct).

Comment: I don't think the main teaching point here is covered in the other question in a specific way: It's been x time. Cela fait  or ça fait. Am I allowed to have an opinion here? Or not?

Comment: @None You're right, the general idea for the verb tenses is the same, but the sentences are quite different, that's why I still answered, focusing on the differences between the sentences. In general, any questions related to translations should be closed anyway, so I guess closing it as duplicate is a "nice" way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> il y a des **nuages** depuis une semaine (there have been **clouds** for a week)
>
> le **ciel** est nuageux depuis une semaine (the **sky** has been cloudy for a week)
>
> le **temps** est nuageux depuis une semaine (the **weather** has been cloudy for a week)

Therefore, **c'est nuageux depuis une semaine** is your most accurate translation. As for the different options, they're all natural and correct, so pick your favorite.